# Hasse principle for high dimensional varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

What is the state-of-the-art of the proof/counterexamples of the Hasse principle for high-dimensional hypersurfaces (say 3-folds or more)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding counterexamples, there is Sarnak-Wang, and then the results of Bjorn Poonen.  Regarding proofs that the Hasse principle holds, I don't know the best result over ALL global fields.  Of course global function fields are $C_2$, thus the Hasse principle trivially holds over global function fields for hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ satisfying $d^2 \leq n$, because these hypersurfaces have rational points.

**Edit.**  I should add that some experts have asked / conjectured about whether the Brauer-Manin obstruction is the only obstruction to the Hasse principle for *every* rationally connected, smooth, projective variety over a global field. Since the Brauer-Manin obstruction vanishes for smooth hypersurfaces of dimension $\geq 3$, in particular these people are asking whether the Hasse principle holds for hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $d\leq n$ and $n\geq 4$.  To my knowledge there are no known counterexamples.

Answer (score 3):

A recent positive result on cubic hypersurfaces:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2385